# In an ASP.NET application, I can't use "/" to go to the root, because I'm using an IIS application. Is there any way around this?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Works just fine in development, but messes up when I post to the server. This is how the href is setup: `"/tools/pages/page.aspx"`. But my web app is an application of the default site in IIS. So the main URL is something like this: `http://domain/mysite/`. So when I use "/" to go to the root, it goes to the domain and not mysite.

I'm expecting this: `http://domain/mysite/tools/pages/page.aspx`, but what I get is this: `http://domain/tools/pages/page.aspx`

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use "/mysite/" instead of "/"?

Comment: @mbeckish Then I couldn't navigate the menus while debugging. I guess that isn't too big of a deal, but I was hoping there was a better method.

Comment: @ernest there is, use `~/` to go to the application root, not the site root.

Comment: @ernest - You could use a configuration parameter to store the base url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use *application-relative* URLs, starting with `~`.
ASP.Net will transform them into absolute paths with the correct prefix.

Note that this will only work in server-side code.

Comment: All of my hrefs are client side.

Comment: You can generate it server-side and store it in hidden variable

Comment: Or you can use helper methods, depending on how you're writing them.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve full URL from Request. Something like

```
string sUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/"));
```